# PDF Hyperlinks on the same file not working with iPhone or iPad

Tags: ios, pdf, adobe, reader

I have made a PDF file with hyperlinks that allow to go to an specific part of that  PDF.

In the PDF, those Hyperlinks work correctly on PC but don't work with iPhone/iPad, also after opening the PDFs with Adobe Acrobat for iOS.
Could you help me please?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. The code is produced by Adobe Reader. It’s an hyperlink for an index and it lets you go to an specific part of page. It is a one page PDF file. Hope I could attach the file.

Comment: Hi, I hyperlinked the index content in pc with Reader Pro. But doesn’t work on iOS. I’ll try with another software, perhaps.